# Xcode app retrieving "now playing" music title even though it's paused

Tags: xcode, macos, itunes

I'm creating a mac app that retrieves the title of the "now playing" music on iTunes.
I'm using this code:

```
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
        NSString* fullTrackName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Now Playing: %@ - %@", iTunes.currentTrack.artist, iTunes.currentTrack.name];
        NSLog(@"%@", fullTrackName);
```

If a music is playing it works just fine, but if i pause iTunes and run the code it will automatically grab the music name, even though it's not playing. 
How can i fix it?
Thank you.
And btw, i'm using iTunes.h and ScriptingBridge.framework for this.

Comment: Presumably it's because it is still "playing" - it's just paused. It's still the current track though.

Comment: yeah, you're right. but is there any way of just grabbing the track title that is currently playing? not paused.

Comment: There must be some kind of player state property on `iTunesApplication` which gives you the state of stopped, playing, paused, etc. Check for that.

Comment: Found what i was looking for:
    if ([iTunes playerState] == iTunesEPlSPlaying){
     //Code if iTunes is not playing
    }   comment so i can vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to look for a player state property on `iTunesApplication` to give you the state of the current track.

Apparently it's like this:

```
if ([iTunes playerState] == iTunesEPlSPlaying) {
    // Code if iTunes is not playing
}
```

Comment: if ([iTunes playerState] == iTunesEPlSPlaying){ //Code if iTunes is not playing }